# Set default language for code-blocks in orgmode

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

Is there a way to define a default language for org-mode code blocks in the docuement header?  Usually, within one org document, I only use one programming language, so it's getting tiresome to always write

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python
[...]
#+END_SRC
```

It would be nice to be able to do something like

```
#+PROPERTY: header-args :session *mysession* :tangle yes :results silent :language python

[...]

#+BEGIN_SRC
[...]
#+END_SRC
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: This does not answer the question on how to set the default language, but it will definitely save you a lot of typing. Typing `<s` followed by the `TAB` key will auto expand into the source code block structure and then you simply need to type `python`, go to the next line and fill in the code.

Comment: Check out http://orgmode.org/manual/Structure-of-code-blocks.html#Structure-of-code-blocks . Seems like the language spec is required. Did you post on the org list? If you didn't, I will, this is an interesting and probably common desire.

Comment: There are two replies already. https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2015-02/msg00604.html

Comment: Thanks, @grettke, for taking the initiative to post to the mailing list.

Comment: The hint from the mailing list above (if one is looking for a solution that does not involve having `#+BEGIN_SRC python` in the `.org` file) is *Probably you would have to modify org-babel-get-src-block-info so that it returns a default when there is nothing after #+BEGIN_SRC*

Comment: Specifically, in `ob-core.el`, the function `org-babel-get-src-block-info` uses `org-element-property` to get the language: code looks like: `(let* ((lang (org-element-property :language datum))`.... This `org-element-property` is defined in `og-element.el`, and it should be possible to advise or replace this `org-element-property`, to return a default when property is `:language`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This answer provides a workable workaround.

The easiest way to do this would be using [easy templates](http://orgmode.org/manual/Easy-Templates.html). Add your templates to the `org-structure-template-alist`:

```
(add-to-list 'org-structure-template-alist
         '("py" "#+BEGIN_SRC python :results output\n?\n#+END_SRC" ""))
```

The question mark indicates the cursor position. Insert the code block with `<py` TAB in this case.

Comment: Your answer is how to add new templates for expansion, not to default the language for a source block.

Comment: While this solves the problem of making it easy to enter such blocks, it doesn't solve the "problem" that the source file still contains `#+BEGIN_SRC python` instead of just `#+BEGIN_SRC` -- this makes the source file a bit harder to read, for example.

Comment: This answer does not work with the new syntax for the structure templates.

Comment: I'm out of the edit window, sorry. The template should now be something like `("py" . "src python :results output")`.